# How to use pymsql parameterized sql query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.6, pymysql

I am trying to use a parameterized SQL query in pymysql.

```
select * from table where id = ? and age = ?
```

and I am creating params list as follows.

```
params = []
params.append(1)
params.append(21)
```

Executing query like this

cursor.execute(query, params)

This is not working. Somehow pymysql is not able to recognize the ? and replacing it values with params.

Comment: use `%s` instead of `?` in your query string

Comment: But can I pass the params like above or I have to do .format() ?

Comment: ```query = 'select * from table where id = %s and age = %s'```. No format. Type of params in docs here: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute